# How can I combine two separately mounted Linux Software RAID1 devices into one?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I'm currently learning Linux software RAID and am trying to perform my first basic reconfiguration. Currently, I have two 3TB HDDs in software RAID1. Unfortunately, I improperly configured this. Right now, there are two MD devices, one /dev/md2 @ 1TB and one /dev/md3 @ 1.7TB. One got mounted to my /home/ directory and the other to my root.

In a perfect world, I would like modify this so that the entire 2.7TB is mounted as the root of the drive.

I currently have a disk setup like so:

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        4096   16781311   16777216    8G Linux RAID
/dev/sda2    16781312   17829887    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3    17829888 2165313535 2147483648    1T Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  2165313536 5860533134 3695219599  1.7T Linux RAID
/dev/sda5        2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        4096   16781311   16777216    8G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2    16781312   17829887    1048576  512M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3    17829888 2165313535 2147483648    1T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  2165313536 5860533134 3695219599  1.7T Linux RAID
/dev/sdb5        2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/md1: 511.4 MiB, 536281088 bytes, 1047424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md0: 8 GiB, 8581545984 bytes, 16760832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md3: 1.7 TiB, 1891818209280 bytes, 3694957440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 1023.9 GiB, 1099377410048 bytes, 2147221504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

And df output:

```
$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev              8037136         0    8037136   0% /dev
tmpfs             1611420     12368    1599052   1% /run
/dev/md2       1056634044 685900556  317036568  69% /
tmpfs             8057084         8    8057076   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         0       5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             8057084         0    8057084   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1           498980    108471     364324  23% /boot
/dev/md3       1818357760    124756 1725842684   1% /home
tmpfs             1611420         0    1611420   0% /run/user/1000
```

What are the steps I need to do to accomplish this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since these are not logical volumes, what you are looking to achieve will be difficult. The only thing you can do is tar archive home and move it to the other disk/root file system then unmount /home remove the partition for home as well as root and then extend the partition for root changing the start/end pointers accordingly through the recovery console. You will obviously need to be very careful with this and assess the risk accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. after moving the data to root, unmounting and deleting partition, use gparted which is graphically managing tool to manage disk partitions. Using this tool you can resize the / partition.